# Project with sass failed to deploy on netlify

Tags: netlify, node-sass

Please help. It's my first time deploying a project with sass on netlify and it always says "Deploy failed" and these appears on the deploy log:

```
     Build failed.
8:13:06 PM: @parcel/namer-default: Target "main" declares an output file path of "index.js"
8:13:06 PM: which does not match the compiled bundle type "html".
8:13:06 PM:   /opt/build/repo/package.json:5:11
8:13:06 PM:     4 |   "description": "",
8:13:06 PM:   > 5 |   "main": "index.js",
8:13:06 PM:   >   |           ^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean "index.html"?
8:13:06 PM:     6 |   "scripts": {
8:13:06 PM:     7 |     "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
8:13:06 PM:    Try changing the file extension of "main" in package.json.
8:13:06 PM: ​
8:13:06 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:13:06 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
8:13:06 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:13:06 PM: ​
8:13:06 PM:   Error message
8:13:06 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
8:13:06 PM: ​
8:13:06 PM:   Error location
8:13:06 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
8:13:06 PM:   npm run build
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: You have to check your package.json file! scripts": { "dev": "parcel src/index.html", hear you are trying to deploy .HTML file instead of index.js.

Comment: Sorry, I just read this now. I actually did that but it didn't work. Adding "targets": {"main": false }" under "main": "index.js" fixed my problem.